# Append DIV after clicking Radio Button using JQuery uses parent data only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I want to create an `input-radio` where users can select their option and fill data inside that option, and expanded another `input-radio` to fill other data. But unluckily whenever the radio is expanded, all the expand data used `Parent-data` only...

**Edited:** Changed snippet for better understanding

You can see it from below:

```js
var index = 0;
$(document).on('click', '.choose_wdv', function() {
    //$(this).nextAll('.wdv_option:first').show();
    //$(this).nextAll('.slm_option:first').hide();
     $(".wdv_option").show();
     $(".slm_option").hide();
});

$(document).on('click', '.choose_slm', function() {
    //$(this).nextAll('.slm_option:first').show();
    //$(this).nextAll('.wdv_option:first').hide();
     $(".slm_option").show();
     $(".wdv_option").hide();
});

$(document).on('click', '.add-form-wdv_slm', addWDVSLMCombination);


function addWDVSLMCombination() {
  index++
  $("#sch8_wdvslm").append('<div class="wdv_slm_container" style="border-style: dotted; border-radius: 10px; border-width: thin; margin-top: 10px;">'+
   '<div class="form-group">'+
    '<label class="control-label" style="padding-left: 25px;">Select Method</label>'+
     '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-outline-warning removeSch8wdvslm">Remove</a>'+
      '<div class="input-group">'+
        '<div class="radio" style="padding-left: 25px;">'+
         '<label><input type="radio" required id="choose_wdv" value="wdvslm_wdv" name="schedule8WDVSLM'+ index +'" class="choose_wdv">WDV</label>'+
          '<label><input type="radio" required id="choose_slm" value="wdvslm_slm" name="schedule8WDVSLM'+ index +'" class="choose_slm">SLM</label>'+
        '</div>'+
      '</div>'+
    '</div>'+

    '<div class="wdv_option" style="display:none;">'+
        '<p style="padding-left: 10px;">AS PER WDV METHOD</p>'+
        '<div class="schedule-container" style="border-style: dotted; border-radius: 10px; border-width: thin; border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px;">'+
          '<div class="col-md-12">'+
           '<div class="row">'+
            '<div class="col-md-2">'+
             '<label for="assetName">Name</label><br>'+
              '<input type="text" id="assetName" name="wdvName[]" class="form-control">'+
                '</div>'+
                 '<div class="col-md-2">'+
                   '<label for="assetDOP">DOP</label><br>'+
                    '<input type="date" id="assetDOP" name="wdvDOP[]" class="form-control date_of_purchase">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-2">'+
                      '<label for="assetOC">OC</label><br>'+
                      '<input type="number" min="0" id="assetOC" name="wdvOC[]" class="form-control originalCost">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-2">'+
                        '<label for="assetWDV">WDV</label><br>'+
                        '<input type="number" min="0" id="assetWDV" name="wdvWDV[]" class="form-control assWDV">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-2">'+
                        '<label for="assetADD">ADD</label><br>'+
                        '<input type="number" min="0" id="assetADD" name="wdvADD[]" class="form-control addition">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-2">'+
                        '<label for="assetEUL">EUL</label><br>'+
                        '<input type="number" min="0" id="assetEUL" name="wdvEUL[]" class="form-control no_of_year">'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>'+

            '<div class="col-md-12" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">'+
                '<div class="row">'+
                    '<div class="col-md-2">'+
                        '<label for="assetBDA">BDA</label><br>'+
                        '<input type="number" readonly min="0" id="assetBDA" name="wdvBDA[]" class="form-control bdaValue">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-2">'+
                        '<label for="assetDays">Day Used</label><br>'+
                        '<input type="number" readonly min="0" id="assetDays" name="wdvDayUsed[]" class="form-control dayUsed">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-2">'+
                        '<label for="assetRateofDep">Rate of Dep.</label><br>'+
                        '<input type="number" readonly min="0" id="assetRateofDep" name="wdvRate[]" class="form-control rateOfDep">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-2">'+
                        '<label for="assetDepAmount">Dep. Amount</label><br>'+
                        '<input type="number" readonly min="0" id="assetDepAmount" name="wdvDepAmount[]" class="form-control depAmount">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-2">'+
                        '<label for="assetNetBlock">Net Block</label><br>'+
                        '<input type="number" readonly min="0" id="assetNetBlock" name="wdvNetBlock[]" class="form-control netBlock">'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
    '</div>'+

    '<div class="slm_option" style="display:none;">'+
        '<p style="padding-left: 10px;">AS PER SLM METHOD</p>'+
        '<div class="schedule-container-slm" style="border-style: dotted; border-radius: 10px; border-width: thin;border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px;">'+
            '<div class="col-md-12">'+
                '<div class="row">'+
                    '<div class="col-md-2">'+
                        '<label for="slmassetName">Name</label><br>'+
                        '<input type="text" id="slmassetName" name="slmName[]" class="form-control">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-2">'+
                        '<label for="slmassetDOP">DOP</label><br>'+
                        '<input type="date" id="slmassetDOP" name="slmDOP[]" class="form-control date_of_purchaseSLM">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-2">'+
                        '<label for="slmassetOC">OC</label><br>'+
                        '<input type="number" min="0" id="slmassetOC" name="slmOC[]" class="form-control originalCostSLM">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-2">'+
                        '<label for="slmassetWDV">WDV</label><br>'+
                        '<input type="number" min="0" id="slmassetWDV" name="slmWDV[]" class="form-control assWDVSLM">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-2">'+
                        '<label for="slmassetADD">ADD</label><br>'+
                        '<input type="number" min="0" id="slmassetADD" name="slmADD[]" class="form-control additionSLM">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-2">'+
                        '<label for="slmassetEUL">EUL</label><br>'+
                        '<input type="number" min="0" id="slmassetEUL" name="slmEUL[]" class="form-control no_of_yearSLM">'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>'+

            '<div class="col-md-12" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">'+
                '<div class="row">'+
                    '<div class="col-md-2">'+
                        '<label for="slmassetBDA">BDA</label><br>'+
                        '<input type="number" readonly min="0" id="slmassetBDA" name="slmBDA[]" class="form-control bdaValueSLM">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-2">'+
                        '<label for="slmassetDays">Day Used</label><br>'+
                        '<input type="number" readonly min="0" id="slmassetDays" name="slmDayUsed[]" class="form-control dayUsedSLM">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-2">'+
                        '<label for="slmassetRateofDep">Rate of Dep.</label><br>'+
                        '<input type="number" readonly min="0" id="slmassetRateofDep" name="slmRate[]" class="form-control rateOfDepSLM">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-2">'+
                        '<label for="slmassetDepAmount">Dep. Amount</label><br>'+
                        '<input type="number" readonly min="0" id="slmassetDepAmount" name="slmDepAmount[]" class="form-control depAmountSLM">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-2">'+
                        '<label for="slmassetNetBlock">Net Block</label><br>'+
                        '<input type="number" readonly min="0" id="slmassetNetBlock" name="slmNetBlock[]" class="form-control netBlockSLM">'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
    '</div>'+

  '</div>');
  $("#sch8_wdvslm").on("click", ".removeSch8wdvslm", function() {
    $(this).closest('.wdv_slm_container').remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wdv_slm_container" style="border-style: dotted; border-radius: 10px; border-width: thin;">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" style="padding-left: 25px;">Select Method</label>
  <div class="input-group">
   <div class="radio" style="    padding-left: 25px;">
     <label><input type="radio" required id="choose_wdv" value="wdvslm_wdv" name="schedule8WDVSLM" class="choose_wdv">WDV</label>
      <label><input type="radio" required id="choose_slm" value="wdvslm_slm" name="schedule8WDVSLM" class="choose_slm">SLM</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wdv_option" style="display:none;">
  <p style="padding-left: 10px;">AS PER WDV METHOD</p>
  <div class="schedule-container" style="border-style: dotted; border-radius: 10px; border-width: thin; border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px;">
  <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
           <label for="assetName">Name</label><br>
              <input type="text" id="assetName" name="wdvName[]" class="form-control">
         </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <label for="assetDOP">DOP</label><br>
                  <input type="date" id="assetDOP" name="wdvDOP[]" class="form-control date_of_purchase">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <label for="assetOC">OC</label><br>
                  <input type="number" min="0" id="assetOC" name="wdvOC[]" class="form-control originalCost">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <label for="assetWDV">WDV</label><br>
                  <input type="number" min="0" id="assetWDV" name="wdvWDV[]" class="form-control assWDV">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <label for="assetADD">ADD</label><br>
                  <input type="number" min="0" id="assetADD" name="wdvADD[]" class="form-control addition">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <label for="assetEUL">EUL</label><br>
                  <input type="number" min="0" id="assetEUL" name="wdvEUL[]" class="form-control no_of_year">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <label for="assetBDA">BDA</label><br>
                  <input type="number" readonly min="0" id="assetBDA" name="wdvBDA[]" class="form-control bdaValue">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <label for="assetDays">Day Used</label><br>
                  <input type="number" readonly min="0" id="assetDays" name="wdvDayUsed[]" class="form-control dayUsed">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <label for="assetRateofDep">Rate of Dep.</label><br>
                  <input type="number" readonly min="0" id="assetRateofDep" name="wdvRate[]" class="form-control rateOfDep">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <label for="assetDepAmount">Dep. Amount</label><br>
                  <input type="number" readonly min="0" id="assetDepAmount" name="wdvDepAmount[]" class="form-control depAmount">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <label for="assetNetBlock">Net Block</label><br>
                  <input type="number" readonly min="0" id="assetNetBlock" name="wdvNetBlock[]" class="form-control netBlock">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slm_option" style="display:none;">
  <p style="padding-left: 10px;">AS PER SLM METHOD</p>
  <div class="schedule-container-slm" style="border-style: dotted; border-radius: 10px; border-width: thin;border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px;">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <label for="slmassetName">Name</label><br>
                  <input type="text" id="slmassetName" name="slmName[]" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <label for="slmassetDOP">DOP</label><br>
                  <input type="date" id="slmassetDOP" name="slmDOP[]" class="form-control date_of_purchaseSLM">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <label for="slmassetOC">OC</label><br>
                  <input type="number" min="0" id="slmassetOC" name="slmOC[]" class="form-control originalCostSLM">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <label for="slmassetWDV">WDV</label><br>
                  <input type="number" min="0" id="slmassetWDV" name="slmWDV[]" class="form-control assWDVSLM">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <label for="slmassetADD">ADD</label><br>
                  <input type="number" min="0" id="slmassetADD" name="slmADD[]" class="form-control additionSLM">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <label for="slmassetEUL">EUL</label><br>
                  <input type="number" min="0" id="slmassetEUL" name="slmEUL[]" class="form-control no_of_yearSLM">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <label for="slmassetBDA">BDA</label><br>
                  <input type="number" readonly min="0" id="slmassetBDA" name="slmBDA[]" class="form-control bdaValueSLM">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <label for="slmassetDays">Day Used</label><br>
                  <input type="number" readonly min="0" id="slmassetDays" name="slmDayUsed[]" class="form-control dayUsedSLM">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <label for="slmassetRateofDep">Rate of Dep.</label><br>
                  <input type="number" readonly min="0" id="slmassetRateofDep" name="slmRate[]" class="form-control rateOfDepSLM">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <label for="slmassetDepAmount">Dep. Amount</label><br>
                  <input type="number" readonly min="0" id="slmassetDepAmount" name="slmDepAmount[]" class="form-control depAmountSLM">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <label for="slmassetNetBlock">Net Block</label><br>
                  <input type="number" readonly min="0" id="slmassetNetBlock" name="slmNetBlock[]" class="form-control netBlockSLM">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

                                                        <div id="sch8_wdvslm"></div>
                                                        <button type="button" style=" margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px!important;" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm add-form-wdv_slm">Add More</button>
```

Maybe the way how I tried is completely wrong also...

I don't want to used `id` to append data cause the expanded maximum is not set and trying to approach using `class name` only.

> Is there any other way to do easily and understandable and to keep 1 class name for the function control

Comment: try with using classname with sibling selector

Comment: I'll check.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/shree/xpvt214o/793020/

You can define variable and increase that variable and append that variable to name section for uniqueness on radio before bind like below for grouping.

```js
var index = 0;
$(document).on('click', '.t1', function() {
 
  $(this).nextAll('.a:first').show();
  $(this).nextAll('.b:first').hide();
});

$(document).on('click', '.t2', function() {
  $(this).nextAll('.b:first').show();
  $(this).nextAll('.a:first').hide();
});

$(document).on('click', '.append-radio', addMoreRadio);

function addMoreRadio() {
  index++
  $('#append_both').append(
    '<input type="radio" name="test_data' + index + '" class="t1"> Test 1' +
    '<input type="radio" name="test_data' + index + '" class="t2">Test 2' +

    '<div class="a" style="display:none;">' +
    'This is Test 1 Expanded' +
    '</div>' +

    '<div class="b" style="display:none;">' +
    'This is Test 2 Expanded' +
    '</div>'
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="test_data" class="t1"> Test 1
<input type="radio" name="test_data" class="t2">Test 2



<div class="a" style="display:none;">
  This is Test 1
</div>

<div class="b" style="display:none;">
  This is Test 2
</div>


<div id="append_both"></div>
<button type="button" class="append-radio">Add More</button>
```

*Note: ID is always unique so use class. Above example I replace your ID to class.*

Comment: After increment also still control the parent value, I want a new value "Test 1 Expanded" below the expanded radio... should I increment the "DIV ID" as well?

Comment: Yeah, it's working perfectly, but I don't know what happens, in my project it cannot work... (a little different than this question)

Comment: $(this).nextAll('.a:first').show(); is not working in my project, but no error in console or network.. any Idea?

Comment: Without see other code it's impossible to say why it's not working on your project.It's not about jquery version.

Comment: Can you look at my code if I updated my snippet to my real project?

Comment: please check the updated snippet, now I didn't use nextVal(); to display the data

Comment: I find your problem. nextAll  only work on sibling and so first of all using parent  find for sibling and after that show hide.

Comment: can you please make a demo, example or something, I am barely to understand the parent, sibling things... ;)

Comment: closest work for you. See this http://jsfiddle.net/shree/xpvt214o/793020/ working example. I remove html and add one two for example.

Comment: yeah, it works perfectly, I try to make parent from my append div, but it should be from the input-radio div... thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: I have made an edit to your comment, and also mark this answer as correct. Can you please review and accepted the edited that I've changed to show others peoples also

Answer (score 1):

i have updated your code, please look into this, if it helps you

```
 $(document).on('click', '.t1', function () {
            if ($(this).parent().attr("id") == "append_both") {
                $(this).nextAll().eq(1).show();
                $(this).nextAll().eq(2).hide();
            }
            else {
                $('#t1_data').show();
                $('#t2_data').hide();
            }
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.t2', function () {
            if ($(this).parent().attr("id") == "append_both") {
                $(this).nextAll().eq(1).show();
                $(this).nextAll().eq(0).hide();
            }
            else {
                $('#t2_data').show();
                $('#t1_data').hide();
            }
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.append-radio', function () {

            var len = $('#append_both hr').length;
            addMoreRadio('test_data' + len);

        });

        function addMoreRadio(name) {
            $('#append_both').append(
              '<hr><input type="radio" name="' + name + '" class="t1"> Test 1' +
              '<input type="radio" name="' + name + '" class="t2">Test 2' +

              '<div class="t1_data" style="display:none;">' +
                'This is Test 1 Expanded' +
              '</div>' +

              '<div class="t2_data" style="display:none;">' +
                'This is Test 2 Expanded' +
              '</div>'
            );
        }
```

Comment: Yeah It is working but one thing whenever we expanded the Radio and select one of the buttons, the previous checked Radio is gone

Comment: as i can see radio button as the same name. so you need to pass radio button name dynamically for each iteration

Comment: @Vpa, i have updated the code as per your requirement, please check once

Comment: Yeah, it's working perfectly. But same issues I got before the nextAll(); cannot work in my project, no errors in console or network.

Comment: please try after updating to latest version of jquery

Comment: Now I used jquery-3.2.1. and also I tried jquery-3.3.1. but still same, maybe I did something wrong.. I'll recheck my code, thank you so much

Comment: please check the updated snippet, now I didn't use nextVal(); to display the data

Comment: Here is the replacement of your code

$(document).on('click', '.choose_wdv', function () {
            $($(this).parentsUntil("div.wdv_slm_container")).parent().find('.wdv_option').show();
            $($(this).parentsUntil("div.wdv_slm_container")).parent().find('.slm_option').hide();
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.choose_slm', function () {
            ($(this).parentsUntil("div.wdv_slm_container")).parent().find('.wdv_option').hide();
            $($(this).parentsUntil("div.wdv_slm_container")).parent().find('.slm_option').show();
        });